# How to show Options page for editor user role

Tags: redux-framework

I am developing a theme, and I want the Theme Options Page, to be available for Editor, and Administrator user roles.

The options page show up fine when the user is an administrator.

My reduxt configuration file:

```php
...
$args = array(
    'display_name'         => esc_html__( 'Ρυθμίσεις Θέματος', TEXT_DOMAIN ),
    'display_version'      => '1.0.0',
    'menu_title'           => esc_html__( 'Ρυθμίσεις Θέματος', TEXT_DOMAIN ),
    'customizer'           => false,
    'page_permissions' => 'delete_pages',
    'dev_mode'          => true
);

Redux::setArgs( $opt_name, $args );

$sections = array(
    'basic',
);

Redux::setSection( $opt_name, array(
    'title'  => esc_html__( 'Βασικές Ρυθμίσεις', TEXT_DOMAIN ),
    'id'     => $sections[0],
    'desc'   => esc_html__( 'Social Media, Στοιχεία Επικοινωνίας', TEXT_DOMAIN ),
    'icon'   => 'el el-home',
    'permissions'       => 'delete_pages',
    'fields' => array(
...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Also add your code to the question itself, not on an external site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it. Line 75 in `redux-framework\redux-core\inc\classes\class-redux-page-render.php`, sets the `page_permissions` argument.

Which of course accepts any valid Wordpress [capability](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#capabilities).